# Mysql Fulltext 50 % threshold

Tags: mysql

I'm using Mysql FULLTEXT search with Natural Language Full-Text, unfortunately I'm stuck with FULLTEXT 50% threshold which is not allow me to search rows if my given keyword occur 50% time of total rows.

I have searched and found a link
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

On this link they have mentioned that

The 50% threshold for natural language searches is determined by the particular weighting scheme chosen. To disable it, look for the following line in myisam/ftdefs.h:

## define GWS_IN_USE GWS_PROB

Change that line to this:

## define GWS_IN_USE GWS_FREQ

I'm unable to locate myisam/ftdefs.h

I'm using Linux OS. Any idea/Suggstions ?

Answer (score 1):

Look for the file in Downloads/mysql-whateverversion/storage/myisam.
(If for some reason it isn't there just search for the file with the command: "sudo find / -name ftdefs.h". This command should provide you with the path to ftdefs.h) Hope this helps.